# Preventing char input into int variables and outputting a single warning message on multiple occurrences

Tags: c++

I have been using a `while` loop in order to clear the wrong input and prompt the user again along with a warning message. However if the user inputs multiple characters, they get extracted into variables on each `cin` statement.

My code:

```
int num = 0;
cin >> num;
while (cin.fail()) {
    cout << "Invalid input. Try again\n";
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
    cin >> num;
}
```

The output after inputting two ‘a’ characters:

```
aa
Invalid input. Try again
Invalid input. Try again
```

Expected output:

```
aa
Invalid input. Try again
```

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have `INT_MAX` be a parameter to `cin.ignore();`, so it looks like this:

```
cin.ignore(INT_MAX);
```

You're not telling cin how much of the buffer you want to ignore. Adding in that will tell cin to ignore everything in the rest of the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num = 0;        
    cin >> num;

    while (cin.fail()) {
        cout << "Invalid input. Try again\n";

        cin.clear();
        cin.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        cin >> num;
    }

    cout << "Input number: " << num << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Results in an infinite loop

Comment: When I input the exact value, the loop is finished. I test this code in visual studio 2017. What is your environment?

Comment: g++ 10.2.0 from MSYS2

Comment: I just test above code on mingw(g++ version: 6.3.0). There is no problem.